# Functional test of a symfony2 controller: How to generate a route

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, controller, phpunit

On a symfony2 controller, I would like to test a controller, which return a `Response` object. My test class extends from `WebTestCase`. I use the `static::createClient()` to get an operational client.

My problem is **to call the good route** on my current installation with a virtual host.

`$client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('my_route', array(), true)` generate a route with localhost as host. But that doesn't work as I have myproject.local as host.

`$client->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` and other dir method provide linux file path, not web path.

I cannot hard code it as I am not alone on the project. So what is the method to get the correct route, or is there another way to test the controller?

Comment: Why do you pass `true` as the third argument to the `generate` method? Do you really need an absolute URL generated?

Comment: Yes, because default url is linked over localhost too.
Or I need another method to test my controller.

Comment: Ain't you using the Symfony's provided test client?

Comment: Yes, those available in Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase

Answer (score 14):

Symfony2's built in test framework (WebTestCase) only needs the relative path to be able to test applications in different environments:

```
$client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('my_route', array(), false);
```

Symfony simulates an http client and tests against an instance of the Kernel created for that test. There are no web servers involved.

You can read more about how the client simulation works here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in Symfony documentation, you should use absolute urls, because change of URLs will impact your end users and thats what you wanna cover in your functional tests too.

> "Hardcoding the request URLs is a best practice for functional tests. If the test generates URLs using the Symfony router, it won't detect any change made to the application URLs which may impact the end users."

See more info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi @serensat thanks for hint, I see the point. I just added the citation of the essential part.